# Why does this tabularx table ignore my width parameter?

Tags: tabularx, width

I can't set my tabularx table \textwidth wide.
I code this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X}
\hline 
\verb|bla bla bla | & fubar fubar fubar \\
\hline
    \verb|bla bla bla| & fubar fubar fubar \\
\hline
    \verb|bla bla bla| & fubar fubar fubar \\
\hline
    \verb|bla bla bla| & fubar fubar fubar \\
\hline\\
end{tabularx}
```

and the output is:

[image]

I'm following the manual. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TeXnician that isn't how tabularx works:-)

Comment: You  have most likely loaded `ltablex` package which documents that it does this unless you use `\preservexcolumns` (a rather unfortunate feature of the package, really)

Comment: Thanks, you've saved my day.

Where can I find examples for using `\preservecolumns`? I googled, but found only this very thread.

Comment: Sorry I mis-rememebred the name it is `\keepXcolumns` and comes up here quite often (which is why I recognised the issue even though you didn't mention the package or post relevant code:-)  https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5CkeepXcolumns